# window.removeEventListener after 3 seconds for function including setInterval?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code which slides content from right to left softly.However, I am trying to stop it after 3 seconds but it doesn't stop because it has Interval function inside. What is the correct way to stop it ?

```
function Marquee(selector, speed) {
  const parentSelector = document.querySelector(selector);
  const clone = parentSelector.innerHTML;
  const firstElement = parentSelector.children[0];
  let i = 0;
  console.log(firstElement);
  parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);
  parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);

  setInterval(function () {
    firstElement.style.marginLeft = `-${i}px`;
    if (i > firstElement.clientWidth) {
      i = 0;
    }
    i = i + speed;
  }, 0);
}


window.addEventListener('load', Marquee('.pot', 1));


setTimeout(function() {
window.removeEventListener('load', Marquee('.pot', 1));
}, 3000);
```

Comment: First issue, an event listener needs to be a function, not the result of calling a function

Comment: There's no point in removing the listener for the `load` event. This event only occurs once. I think what you're probably looking for is `clearInterval()`.